# JavaFX on Raspberry Pi Zero W: Slow Transition Effects (low fps)

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi

I quick and dirty programmed a very small image slide show application using javafx to run on my Raspberry Pi Zero W. In this application I am using FadeTransition for the images. It's all working fine but I unfortunately have the issue that it's quite slow, so the fade transitions don't look smooth (too low fps).

First, I increased the vRam to 128Mb (I also tried 256Mb before).Then, I played around with these parameters in various combinations:

-Dprism.forceGPU=true

-Dprism.order=j2d,sw

-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true

I even overclocked the pi to 1100Mhz. But the problem still remains, the transition effects are still very slow.

I also tried to run my application without lightdm as I read multiple times on the internet that java is able to write directly to the display buffer. But I could not get the application to run this way.

**Do you have an idea if it's even possible to run this smoothly on a raspberry pi zero?**

Thank you very much!

---

Snippet of my java code:

```
FileInputStream input = null;
FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(transitionTime * 1000 / 2), imageView);
fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
fadeIn.setToValue(1.0);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(transitionTime * 1000 / 2), imageView);

fadeOut.setFromValue(1.0);
fadeOut.setToValue(0);
fadeOut.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {

   while (true) {
    try {
     long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

     if (currentTime > lastRefreshTime + showingTimePerImage * 1000) {

      File file = getNewRandomFileFromFolder();

      input = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
      Image image = new Image(input);

      fadeOut.setOnFinished(new EventHandler < ActionEvent > () {
       @Override
       public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        imageView.setImage(image);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(primaryStage.heightProperty());
        fadeIn.play();
       }
      });

      fadeOut.play();

      lastRefreshTime = currentTime;
     }
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not know JavaFX, but I wonder if it has something to do with your threading. Perhaps you should show more of your code, where you make the threads and run them. Also, is it kosher to be manipulating the user-interface with your image display from a background thread?

Comment: @BasilBourque - manipulating the UI from a background thread is not allowed in JavaFX, however - the `onFinished` event of any JavaFX animation is guaranteed to be called on the UI thread, so there is no problem there.  
There is however a question of whether the loop is indeed running on a separate thread. @user1250100 - can you share the part of the code which actually starts the thread? You might also want to consider using `Thread.sleep` so the loop is less resource-intensive, or maybe use `Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: @Itai Regarding the issue of being on the UI thread, notice that `fadeOut.play` is being called outside of that `setOnFinished`. Might that be a UI manipulation from the background thread?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments!
I uploaded my complete file (it's really just one) here:
https://pastebin.com/N6KwZ4Gt

You can take a look, I will check your hints later, thanks! :-)

Comment: Hey there, I thought about your hints. I see that there are javafx function calls in my worker thread. I didn't know that its a problem. Would it in your opinion better to just set an flag in the worker thread and check this within the ui thread for being changed to initiate the image fade?

Thread0: javafx + check flag, Thread1: Timer + load image + set flag

Better this way? Thank you!